# What does vertical yellow dashed line mean in grafana panel for alerting

Tags: grafana, alert

As I understand,

- If an alert is triggered, a **red** vertical dashed line is drawn (not shown in the figure)
- If an alert becomes OK, a **green** vertical dashed line is drawn.
- What does a **yellow** dashed vertical line mean? I haven't found a doc about the interpretation of colors in grafana.

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's something like beginning of alert's pending status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The yellow dashed line represents an alert in ***PENDING*** status.

[image: Pending Annotation Example]

Note that you can hover your cursor over the triangles along the x axis (at the bottom of the dashed lines) to get a popup telling you more about the annotation.

For more information on the different states you can reference this documentation https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/fundamentals/alert-rules/state-and-health/.